# Pandas (dataframe) - Select value in each row from several columns, that is in 1 of 3 lists with differing priority

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column of values that depends on the values in other columns. For each row in each column of selected columns, compare the values across each column. Select the value that is a value within list 1, else select the value that is within list 2 otherwise select the value that is within list 3.
Together list 1 (`L1`), 2 (`L2`) and 3 (`L3`) contain all possible values. Also within each list select the highest value.

In reality the dataframe contains more columns that should not be searched, also the dataframe contains some more columns to be searched. In addition there are many more rows than given in the code here, also the lists (`L1`, `L2`, `L3`) contain many more values. The example here is just given as a MWE.

I arrived at this code:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

L1 = [1, 5, 9]
L2 = [8, 3, 6]
L3 = [2, 4, 7]

txt = u'''id    col1            col2           col3    
A                1               9              8
B                5               6              9
C                9               1              4
D                3               8              7
F                6               3              1
G                8               5              7
'''

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+")

m1 = (df['col1'].isin(L1) & df['col3'].isin(L2)) | (~df['col1'].isin(L1) & df['col1'].isin(L2) & df['col3'].isin(L3))
m2 = (df['col3'].isin(L1) & df['col1'].isin(L2)) | (~df['col3'].isin(L1) & df['col3'].isin(L2) & df['col1'].isin(L3))

m3 = (df['col2'].isin(L1) & df['col3'].isin(L2)) | (~df['col2'].isin(L1) & df['col2'].isin(L2) & df['col3'].isin(L3))
m4 = (df['col3'].isin(L1) & df['col2'].isin(L2)) | (~df['col3'].isin(L1) & df['col3'].isin(L2) & df['col2'].isin(L3))

m5 = (df['col2'].isin(L1) & df['col1'].isin(L2)) | (~df['col2'].isin(L1) & df['col2'].isin(L2) & df['col1'].isin(L3))
m6 = (df['col1'].isin(L1) & df['col2'].isin(L2)) | (~df['col1'].isin(L1) & df['col1'].isin(L2) & df['col2'].isin(L3))


df['FinalSelection'] = np.select([m1|m2, m3|m4, m5|m6], [df['col1'], df['col2'], df['col3']], default=df['col1'])
```

Which outputs the following:

```
id  col1    col2    col3           FinalSelection
A   1        9       8                    1
B   5        6       9                    6
C   9        1       4                    9
D   3        8       7                    3
F   6        3       1                    6
G   8        5       7                    8
```

**EDIT** (Corrected typo in final selection column)
However the last column (FinalSelection) is wrong and is supposed to be:

```
FinalSelection
      9
      9
      9
      8
      1
      5
```

So in short words I want to select the value from list 1 if is available on that row in the columns that we search. Otherwise from list 2. Else select from list 3. Also within each list select the highest number. [In reality we are actually selecting the values in the dataframe itself, not the lists.]

How may this be done?

Comment: I was working on this, but my result is different from what you are asking for because I'm confused about what you're looking for: I understood that, from the first row of your dataframe (1, 9, 8), you want the highest value available in L1 if that exists. Since L1 is [1, 5, 9], then the result should be 9. Yet your output says 1. Can you please clarify what your algorithm is supposed to be doing?

Comment: You are absolutely right, typo from my side. Result should be 9. Corrected that now. You understood very well what the algorithm is supposed to be doing as I interpret your comment.

Comment: Doesn't that apply to the other rows as well? My solution gives the following values for the `FinalSelection` column: `[9, 9, 9, 8, 1, 5]`. The second and third rows also have a 9, which is present in L1, etc.

Comment: Oh, I see that you changed it now. See my solution below then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
def select(row):
    for lst in [L1, L2, L3]:
        for val in sorted(row[1:], reverse=True):
            if val in lst:
                return val

df['Final Selection'] = df.apply(select, axis=1)
```